# Power series representation of $f(x) = $ln$(5-x)$

Tags: calculus

This was part of an answer posted as a solution to the problem. Of course after differentiating you would need to integrate to get back to $f(x)$ but this part has been left out as it's the differentiation part I am stuck on.

Question: Find the power series representation for the function and determine the radius of convergence.

$f(x) = $ln$(5-x)$

$$f'(x) = -\frac{1}{5-x}$$

$$= - \frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{1-1/5x}$$

$$= - \frac{1}{5} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{5}x)^n$$

$$= -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{5^{n+1}}$$

The last step is where I am confused. In the denominator where are they getting the $n+1$ from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get it from the $\frac{1}{5}$ in front of the sum. Since it is not dependent on the index of the sum you can freely move it.

$$
\frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{5^n}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{x^n}{5^n}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{5^{n+1}}
$$

You could also remove $\frac{1}{5}$ as many times you like

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{5^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{5^n}= \frac{1}{5^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{5^{n-1}}
$$

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

They just moved the $\frac{1}{5}$ factor inside the sum.

Answer (score 1):

YOu went from

$$= - \frac{1}{5} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{5}x)^n$$

to

$$= -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{5^{n+1}}$$

As an intermediate step, you have

$$= - \frac{1}{5} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{5^n}$$

Now bring in the constant...

$$= -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{5} \frac{x^n}{5^n}$$